# send hyperlink query string to server and get result using jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

i am making a simple site in php. I have a product page and there is a link on product page that says add to wishlist so when a user clicks on that link the product is posted to the server and the page is redirected from the backend. but I want to do it using jquery ajax so that my page is not reloaded. can somebody please provide a snippet of code on how to do that ?

Comment: In [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there are many examples you can use.

Comment: @VisioN. Am I the only one or the site is down at the moment?

Comment: @gdoron Hm.. Seems to be down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#anchorId').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"foo",
        data : "the query string",
        ...
        ...
        success: function(result){
                // success code.
            }
        });

    return false; // prevents the default behavior of anchor click.
});
```

The best way to learn jQuery, is to visit the [**API site**](http://api.jquery.com/).    (Which seems to be down at the moment)
The [ajax category](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

---

**Update:**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.foo', function(){
    // What you want here.
    return false;
}
```

This will catch any click on anchors with the `foo` class under `<body>` no matter when they were created("runtime" or with the page load) .

Comment: but in my case I have say 100 products on each page. so anchors are being generated at runtime. The problem is that query string and anchors are created at runtime so cant use their id's

Comment: @FaizanAli. Don't you think that data should be in the question body? why are you saying it just now? how the query string look like? how do you build it?

Comment: thanks.. that is answers my question.. I need it to be a class and not the identity. rest I will sort out .. thanks a lot for your help !!